# Formatting multidimensional array data days wise

Tags: php, laravel-5, multidimensional-array

Hi I have data response for few days in day sorting order like

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 13:00:00
            [end_time] => 13:20:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => sun
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 14:40:00
            [end_time] => 15:00:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => sun 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 10:00:00
            [end_time] => 10:20:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => mon
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 16:00:00
            [end_time] => 16:20:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => mon
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 15:40:00
            [end_time] => 16:00:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => tue
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 15:20:00
            [end_time] => 15:40:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => tue
        )
)
```

and I want reformat array in day wise like

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sun] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 13:00:00
            [end_time] => 13:20:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => sun
        )
    
        [mon] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 10:00:00
            [end_time] => 10:20:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => mon
        )
        
        [tue] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 15:40:00
            [end_time] => 16:00:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => tue
        )
    )
    
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sun] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 14:40:00
            [end_time] => 15:00:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => sun 
        )
    
        [mon] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 16:00:00
            [end_time] => 16:20:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => mon
        )
        
        [tue] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 15:20:00
            [end_time] => 15:40:00
            [date] => 2020-08-30
            [day] => tue
        )
    )
)
```

for this I code as

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($week_days as $key1 => $v) {
        $i = 0;
        $response[$key][$v]['start_time'] = $value->start_time;
        $response[$key][$v]['end_time'] = $value->end_time;
        $response[$key][$v]['date'] = $value->date;
        $response[$key][$v]['day'] = $value->day;
        $response[$key][$v]['have_appointment'] = $value->have_appointment;
        $response[$key][$v]['patient_name'] = $value->patient_name;
        $response[$key][$v]['complain'] = $value->complain;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

but seems it overwrite data & I could not catch where I am making mistake

Comment: How come same date is applicable to different days logically speaking?

Comment: `30-08-2020` is a Sunday only.

Comment: This question feels Unclear.  Is this a realistic [mcve]?  Please always express your iterable data as `var_export()` or a json string, so that volunteers can instantly use your sample data.

Comment: Your code does not resemble your data.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea the logical reason for this sorting nor do I fully understand how your data may vary, but as I understand it, you will need to group your data by day values, then transpose the structure to make sure that no subarray in the final output has the same `day` property twice.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V4Qfa))

```
foreach ($data as $object) {
    $temp[$object->day][] = $object;
}

var_export(
    array_map(null, ...array_values($temp))
);
```

My output loses the redundant/temporary grouping key (`day`) while transposing -- I assume you don't need the duplicated value.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'start_time' => '13:00:00',
       'end_time' => '13:20:00',
       'date' => '2020-08-30',
       'day' => 'sun',
    ),
    1 => 
    (object) array(
       'start_time' => '10:00:00',
       'end_time' => '10:20:00',
       'date' => '2020-08-30',
       'day' => 'mon',
    ),
    2 => 
    (object) array(
       'start_time' => '15:40:00',
       'end_time' => '16:00:00',
       'date' => '2020-08-30',
       'day' => 'tue',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'start_time' => '14:40:00',
       'end_time' => '15:00:00',
       'date' => '2020-08-30',
       'day' => 'sun',
    ),
    1 => 
    (object) array(
       'start_time' => '16:00:00',
       'end_time' => '16:20:00',
       'date' => '2020-08-30',
       'day' => 'mon',
    ),
    2 => 
    (object) array(
       'start_time' => '15:20:00',
       'end_time' => '15:40:00',
       'date' => '2020-08-30',
       'day' => 'tue',
    ),
  ),
)
```